# jquery tablesorter class sticky-false

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tablesorter

I'm using jquery plugin tablesorter with the sticky headers widget .
In the documentation it is stated that a class called sticky-false was added .
But I cant manage to hide the sticky-headers on specific columns.,

I have no options set on my javascript and I start tablesorter like this. ... Works.

```
$('#table').tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra','stickyHeaders', 'filter'] }
```

and on my table add the following, ... sticky-false wont work, other two work but input box doesnt dissapear

```
<th class="sticky-false filter-false sorter-false">Table</th>
```

Im using TableSorter 2.14.5 and tableSorter 2.8+ widgets

Anyone knows a way to hide the input box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "sticky-false" class is meant for an entire row, not an individual column.

```
<tr class="sticky-false">
    <th class="sorter-false" colspan="5">This row will not be sticky</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="filter-false sorter-false">Column 1</th>
    ...
    <th>Column 5</th>
</tr>
```

If you want to hide a column filter, use the following css:

```
.tablesorter-filter-row .disabled { display: none; }
```